# Separating out jQuery $(this) into ajax?

Tags: jquery, arrays, this, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to use the following coordinates in a separate php file and I guess the best way is to transfer via ajax.

The html is as follows:

```
 <div id="canvas">
 <div class="point1">
 <div class="coord"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="point2">
 <div class="coord"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="point3">
 <div class="coord"></div>
 </div> etc
 </div>
```

The jQuery UI draggable function I've currently written currently shows the top and left position of each div directly underneath the div being dragged:

```
...
element = this;
var top = $(this).position().top;
var left = $(this).position().left;
$('.coord', this).text('Top: ' + top + 'px' + ' Left: ' + left + 'px');
...
```

But in order to now use each of the point coordinates in PHP variables do I need to split out `$('.coordinates', this) etc` into an array first to transfer via ajax into php - and if so does anyone know how?

Or is there a simpler way - as I'm sure there probably is?!? I'm just a bit confused!

Appreciate any advice or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not so advanced but if you wanna pass data from javascript(jquery) to PHP and as you say with ajax use the jquery method $.post:

```
    $.post("file.php", { coordTop: top , coordLeft: left },
  function(data) {// ON REQUEST DONE YOU CAN RETURN (echo, print,..) DATA
    alert("Data: " + data);
  });
```

And in the PHP file you catch those vars whith $_POST["coordTop"] and $_POST["coordLeft"]

Comment: Yeah i know about the ajax post method itself, i'm just not sure if I need to create separate variables for each of the coordinates or whether its done differently.

Comment: Now I understand, sorry... First make an array of the points, pass it as: .."file.php", { points: arrPoints }.. and later in the PHP work with what you receive in the $_POST["points"]... I'm gonna see it and if works I post the code.

Comment: Ok, I have it. As what I've seen of your HTML I would pass a JSON within every coord:
 'JSON.stringify(arrPoints)' where arrPoints is a: 'arrPoints = {}; $(".coord").each(function(index, element) { arrPoints[$(this).parent().attr("class")] = $(this).text();}'
and later in the PHP use 
'$arrPoints = json_decode($_POST["points"]);'

Comment: Ah OK I think I get it. Don't suppose you could do a jsfiddle of that as the formatting in your comment makes it a little confusing to read? Really appreciate your idea.

Comment: Oh, I never use it, hope it works: http://jsfiddle.net/PKhf7/ ... This is an approach, then in your PHP you will have to get the left and top separately and I suggest changing everything and make for e.g. that your ui-draggable in addition of refresh the coord div, refresh two hidden fields or divs. Another way is to explode each var with a separator known by you like X;Y X, Y but is less safe.

Comment: Awesome, I get the idea now. Nice one! Thanks - really appreciated. I'll mark the original answer as correct, even though its this latest code that's working.